# Design an ordered list with a border in the exact middle of two li-elemens

Tags: css, list, html-lists

I have designed the following list. Now I want to keep its exact appearance but put more space inbetween the li-elements. Unfortunately with "padding-bottom" it moves the border-bottom in a way that it does NOT stay exact in the middle between two elements but glues to the bottom, as it is supposed to do, I see that. But I would love to put it in a manner that it stays EXACTELY in the middle of the two neigbored li-elements. Right now I am stuck. i know I could mess around with the html source but I would rather want to keep it clean and do this only with CSS. Can anyone point me somewhere fruitful? Thanks!

```
   <div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">No hacemos uso de cualquier de los componentes prefabricados o mezclas preparadas.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Una alta calidad en la compra de los ingredientes y la preparación es nuestra principal prioridad. </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Todos nuestros productos se hacen con amor y se han inspirado en recetas familiares.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Punto tres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Queremos que nuestros clientes estén satisfechos. Si alguna vez tiene motivo de queja, le pedimos que nos devuelva su compra tan pronto como sea posible en nuestra tienda.</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

    #list {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 30px;
      text-align:center;
    }

    #list ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    #list ul li {
      font: 200 14px/1.5 'oswaldlight';
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #list ul li:last-child {
      border: none;
    }

    #list li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
      text-align:center;

      -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #list li a:hover {
      font-size: 30px;
      background: #f6f6f6;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the value between `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`?

```
#list ul li {
    padding:2px 0;
}
```

That will have a padding of 2px on both the top and bottom of your `li` element, keeping the border in the middle instead of glued to the bottom.

Comment: That is as straight as obvious. Thanks, sir. I should have seen this. I was so occupied with thinking that I did not pay attention to trigger the border in such a ways. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML :**

```
 <div id="list">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">No hacemos uso de cualquier de los componentes prefabricados o mezclas preparadas.</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Una alta calidad en la compra de los ingredientes y la preparación es nuestra principal prioridad. </a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Todos nuestros productos se hacen con amor y se han inspirado en recetas familiares.</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Punto tres</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Queremos que nuestros clientes estén satisfechos. Si alguna vez tiene motivo de queja, le pedimos que nos devuelva su compra tan pronto como sea posible en nuestra tienda.</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
 #list {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 30px;
      text-align:center;
    }

    #list ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    #list ul li {
      font: 200 14px/1.5 'oswaldlight';
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 5px 0px;
    }

    #list ul li:last-child {
      border: none;
    }


    #list li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
      text-align:center;

      -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #list li a:hover {
      font-size: 30px;
      background: #f6f6f6;
    }
```

I think this will resolve your problem.